# How do I get the likes length to update in real time after clicking clicking like

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I click to remove the first like on the first goal, I can see the Redux action firing (using Redux DevTools) for the like being updated. But the number beside is not updating. When I check the console it doesn't appear that anything is refreshing. When I refresh the page, it shows the updated number that was previously liked (the 0 becomes a 1), but I have to refresh the page to see this update. **How can I get the number to update in real time without having to refresh the page?**

[image]

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addLike, removeLike } from "../../actions/goal";
import { getGoals } from "../../actions/goal";
import Spinner from "../layout/Spinner";
import Navbar from "../dashboard/Navbar";
import ThumbUpAltIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ThumbUpAlt";
import ThumbDownAltIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ThumbDownAlt";
import ChatIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Chat";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import DoneIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Done";
import {
  Typography,
  Container,
  CssBaseline,
  makeStyles,
  Grid,
  Avatar,
  Paper,
  Button
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paper: {
    height: "auto",
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(3)
  },
  actionButtons: {
    marginTop: "3vh"
  },
  profileHeader: {
    textAlign: "center",
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  avatar: {
    width: theme.spacing(7),
    height: theme.spacing(7)
  }
}));

const Goals = ({
  getGoals,
  auth,
  addLike,
  removeLike,
  goal: { goals, user, loading }
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getGoals();
  }, [getGoals]);

  const classes = useStyles();


  return loading ? (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className={classes.paper}>
          <Spinner />
        </div>
      </Container>
    </>
  ) : (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Navbar />
      <main>
        <Container>
          <Typography variant="h2" className={classes.profileHeader}>
            Goals
          </Typography>
          {/* parent grid */}
          <Grid container spacing={4}>
            {goals.map(singleGoal => (
              <Grid
                className={classes.paper}
                key={singleGoal._id}
                spacing={1}
                container
                item
                direction="row"
                alignItems="center"
                component={Paper}
              >
                <Grid
                  item
                  container
                  direction="column"
                  justify="center"
                  alignItems="center"
                  xs={3}
                >
                  <Avatar className={classes.avatar} src={singleGoal.avatar} />
                  <Typography variant="caption">
                    {singleGoal.first_name} {singleGoal.last_name}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="caption" className={classes.postedOn}>
                    Posted on{" "}
                    <Moment format="MM/DD/YYYY">{singleGoal.date}</Moment>
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid container item direction="column" xs={9}>
                  <Typography variant="body1">{singleGoal.text}</Typography>
                  <Grid item className={classes.actionButtons}>

                    <Button size="small" onClick={e => addLike(singleGoal._id)}>
                      <ThumbUpAltIcon />
                    </Button>

                    <Typography variant="caption">
                      {singleGoal.likes.length}
                    </Typography>
                    <Button
                      size="small"
                      onClick={e => removeLike(singleGoal._id)}
                    >
                      <ThumbDownAltIcon />
                    </Button>


                      <Button href={`/goal/${singleGoal._id}`} size="small">
                        <ChatIcon />
                      </Button>

                    {!auth.loading && singleGoal.user === auth.user._id && (
                      <Button size="small">
                        <DoneIcon />
                      </Button>
                    )}
                    {!auth.loading && singleGoal.user === auth.user._id && (
                      <Button size="small">
                        <DeleteIcon />
                      </Button>
                    )}
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

Goals.propTypes = {
  getGoals: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  goal: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  goal: state.goal,
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getGoals, addLike, removeLike })(
  Goals
);
```

Comment: no of like you should get from backend side(api)

Comment: pass you selected row to action and from action to reducer then update there.... it will show in real time.

Comment: What do you mean by selected row?

Comment: I think the easy way to update real time is setState of the like in page and take action to reducer to update with DB

Comment: @KhanhLeTran I'm having trouble visualizing what that would look like. Are you saying to something like this: `[like, updateLike] = useState(false)`?

Answer (score 1):

I will need to see the rest of your code to be sure, but it seems you are dispatching your action but you are not updating your store, it could be a mistake in your reducer.

Comment: The store is being updated I believe. Because when I refresh of the page it changes to 1.

Comment: are you saving those likes in a database and getting that data after the component did mount? if that is the case, It's possible you are executing correctly the request but you are not dispatching your action correctly, this could be the reason why you see the correct number after refreshing the page.